# Monaco supports Classic Edge, Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera but is not supported on mobile browsers and web frameworks

Tags: mobile, browser, monaco-editor

From their [website](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/):

> About
>
> The Monaco Editor is the code editor that powers VS Code. A good page
>   describing the code editor's features is here.
>
> It is licensed under the MIT License and supports Classic Edge, Edge,
>   Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera.
>
> The Monaco editor is not supported in mobile browsers or mobile web
>   frameworks.
>
> Find more information at the Monaco Editor repo.

What does this exactly mean? Are there known issues/restrictions or is this only meant to make sure they do not have to guarantee support/a working editor? (Manually tested on my ios 13.4.1 safari, seems ok)
Does this mean, no issues for e.g. android will be fixed, but generally it is intended to work there too?
The information on their website seems not clear to me, any directions, hints please?

EDIT: Found a promising open PR in their [issues](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are correct in your assessment of the statement:

> The Monaco editor is not supported in mobile browsers or mobile web frameworks.

So, while you may be able to integrate monaco into an application targeting an unsupported platform, you do so at your own risk, meaning you aren't guaranteed any official support nor will your issues generated on unsupported platforms receive attention from the project team.

For what it's worth, there are a few mobile applications which use monaco but the functionality is very limited, mostly due to the lack of traditional "desktop" input devices (dual button mouse, physical keyboard).